# Make Firefox use single quotes when logging strings

Tags: firefox, console.log, firefox-developer-tools

Logging JSON or HTML strings in the Chrome console is nice because there's few escape strings and it's both easily readable and copyable:

```
> JSON.stringify({ a: 'b' })
< "{"a":"b"}"
> '<div class="square">'
< "<div class="square">"
```

The node REPL is even better, because it logs syntactically correct content:

```
> JSON.stringify({ a: 'b' })
'{"a":"b"}'
> '<div class="square">'
'<div class="square">'
```

Chrome's `"{"a":"b"}"` is not a valid JS string, but Node's `'{"a":"b"}'` is.

Firefox however, uses double quotes when logging strings, and escapes the double quotes characters, so its logs are valid JS, but are neither easy to read not copyable.

```
> JSON.stringify({ a: 'b' })
< "{\"a\":\"b\"}"
> '<div class="square">'
< "<div class=\"square\">"
```

I'd like to configure the Firefox devtools to use single quotes when logging strings, just like Node does, is there a hack for that?

I am aware of [this bugzilla issue](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1375328) on the subject, but it's 3 human years old (aka 30 internet years old), and no one has been assigned to this issue, but perhaps there is a hidden configuration that can be done.

Comment: Note that the age of an issue doesn't say anything about whether or not it will get implemented at some point, just that it wasn't prioritized so far. I already saw [things get implemented 20 (!) years after they got filed](https://bugzil.la/40545) and others that got implemented only a few days later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With linking to the related Bugzilla issue you already gave the answer yourself.

In there, [one of the developers wrote that he'd rather not add a preference to control this](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1375328#c6). So that means there is currently no way to change that, unfortunately.

I've also dug through the DevTools code, and [indeed the double quotes in strings are currently (as of Firefox 84) hard coded](https://searchfox.org/mozilla-central/rev/81fbdf7119fad8035274e3df409ca76572685bf3/devtools/client/shared/components/reps/reps/rep-utils.js#142-174).

So the best way forward here is by commenting on the issue and describing your use case.